# Blackberry focus-based navigation for regular web applications

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, mobile

Blackberry's HTML 5 Webworks allows you to develop applications in HTML5+JS which take advantage of Blackberry's special abilities. For instance, you can set up your application so that it can use the touchpad to navigate UI elements instead of using a cursor (i.e. move touchpad down, next UI element is focused).

Does anyone know if you can do this for regular web applications? I would like to develop a web application which uses the touchpad when running on a Blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/using_the_navigation_mode_1866978_11.html

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.focus.html

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Comment: I believe that's for Webworks' apps, that doesn't work on a page loaded through the browser, right?